# Restful authentication + Facebook connect - User model redesign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, facebook, data-modeling, restful-authentication

I have a site with Restful authentication as authentication plugin. I need to integrate Facebook connect. Facebook does not provide email address for the user (maybe only if user agrees if), and of course does not provide a password.

The main issue is that the User model has a lot of `validates_**` on those 2 fields (from Restful authentication modules).
Another little issue would be that we already have a lot of code (observers sending emails after user creation, etc etc) that depends on email address.
The solution present in the facebook_connect tutorials was to save the user model bypassing validations, but this is sooo wrong..

How would you *redesign the User model* to *include any/both of the authentication methods*(standard and/or facebook_connect)?

1. Refactor all validations (with :unless => :is_facebook_user), put conditions on observers, etc.
2. Implement STI on User table (and have StandardUser / FacebookUser, each with custom authentication modules)
3. User table having polymorphic reference to standard_user and facebook_user
4. Other ideea

Please notice that the functionality to link a 'standard' account to a 'facebook' account is also required, which complicates things.

References:

http://crazyviraj.blogspot.com/2010/01/test-cases-for-basic-facebook-connect.html

http://blog.yangtheman.com/2009/08/23/how-to-integrate-facebook-connect-with-a-rails-app/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1):

A good example to get your started [here](https://github.com/madebymany/restful-authentication-facebook-connect-tutorial).